# Subset df on value and subsequent row - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know this is in S0 somewhere but I can't seem to find it. I want to subset a df on a specific value and include the following unique rows. Using below, I can return values equal to `A`, but I'm hoping to return the next unique values, which is `B`.

Note: The subsequent unique value may not be `B` or may have varying rows, so I need a function that finds the returns all subsequent unique values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],             
    'ID' : ['A','A','B','B','C','C','A','A','B','B','C','C'],      
    'Val' : [2.0,5.0,2.5,2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,4.0,2.0,5.0,1.0],   
    })

df = df[df['ID'] == 'A']
```

intended output:

```
    Time ID  Val
0      1  A  2.0
1      1  A  5.0
2      1  B  2.5
3      1  B  2.0
4      2  A  1.0
5      2  A  6.0
6      2  B  4.0
7      2  B  2.0
```

Comment: `df[df['ID'].shift().eq('A') & df['ID'].ne('A')]`?

Comment: Does B always follow A

Comment: No, it could be any unique string. It could also be any number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok OP let me do this again, you want to find all the rows which are "A" (base condition) and all the rows which are following a "A" row at some point, right ?

Then,

```
is_A = df["ID"] == "A"
not_A_follows_from_A = (df["ID"] != "A") &( df["ID"].shift() == "A")
candidates = df["ID"].loc[is_A | not_A_follows_from_A].unique()
df.loc[df["ID"].isin(candidates)]
```

Should work as intented.

Edit : example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'Time': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 'ID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'F'],
 'Val': [7, 2, 7, 5, 1, 6, 7, 3, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2]})
is_A = df["ID"] == "A"
not_A_follows_from_A = (df["ID"] != "A") &( df["ID"].shift() == "A")
candidates = df["ID"].loc[is_A | not_A_follows_from_A].unique()
df.loc[df["ID"].isin(candidates)]
```

outputs this :

```
    Time ID  Val
0      1  A    7
1      1  A    2
2      1  B    7
3      0  B    5
7      1  A    3
8      0  E    2
9      0  E    4
10     1  E    7
11     1  A    8
12     1  F    2
```

Comment: This works if the same unique value always follows A. Is there also a way to pass multiple unique values? Say the col is filled with A-Z, I'm currently getting A and B. Is there a way to get A-F?

Comment: I made it that it would grab different values only if the preceding value is "A", I'll add an example.  Could you add an example with more possibilities and the expected output ?

Comment: @JPA0888 correct , so is may answer does what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `drop_duplicates`, then `groupby` select the number of unique ID we would like to keep by `head`, and `merge`

```
out = df.merge(df[['Time','ID']].drop_duplicates().groupby('Time').head(2))
   Time ID  Val
0     1  A  2.0
1     1  A  5.0
2     1  B  2.5
3     1  B  2.0
4     2  A  1.0
5     2  A  6.0
6     2  B  4.0
7     2  B  2.0
```